# Add reference to web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services

I'm generating a web service from a wsdl and have some methods in it with attributes.

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://link/update", ReplyAction="*")]
WebServices.updateResponse update(WebServices.updateRequest request);
```

When I try add a reference to this service in my VS2010 project there are no methods at all.

After I change the attribute

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContract]
WebServices.updateResponse update(WebServices.updateRequest request);
```

the methods are all then available.

What is wrong in the first situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.ServiceModel.OperationContract - is a short version of System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute. The problem is in your ReplyAction="*" which break your metadata (means the WsdlExporter will ignore that Operation). Try to set it to any other value.

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.replyaction.aspx):

> In addition to specifying a particular value for the action header of
>   the reply message, you can also specify the string "*" (an asterisk).
>   Specifying an asterisk in the service instructs WCF not to add a reply
>   action to the message, which is useful if you are programming against
>   messages directly. Specifying an asterisk in a client application
>   instructs WCF not to validate the reply action.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/508e893d-f205-4ea5-b02f-3934b06ce9ca/) there is no difference.  C# transforms OperationContract into OperationContractAttribute

Comment: So... there are no methods, when I try to add a reference to the service in first situation. And I try to find the reason